# How to efficiently assign values (e.g. colours) to edges in WebGL

Tags: webgl, webgl2

I'm working with 3D meshes (mostly triangle meshes, though occasionally quad- or general polygonal meshes) for which I compute a value for each edge. This value I'd like to visualise using a colour map, i.e. render each edge in a colour corresponding to its associated value.

Is there a way to assign values to edges in WebGL that is more efficient than using a typical `drawArrays` approach? That is, looping over the edges and storing the vertices pair-wise in a buffer (resulting in a lot of duplicated x, y, z coordinate data) and introducing an additional vertex attribute storing the edge value (the same value for both vertices)?

In OpenGL, I'd use a `drawElements` approach, store the edge values in a texture (or buffer texture), and then use `gl_PrimitiveID` in the fragment shader to look up the relevant edge value for the edge currently being processed. Unfortunately, WebGL doesn't know about `gl_PrimitiveID`, and I don't see a way to emulate it. I briefly thought about instanced rendering (using `gl_InstanceID`), but that would complicate things and probably end up not being much more efficient...

Comment: Have you measured the performance of each of the approaches? Using `gl_PrimitiveID` is likely to be much slower because of its cache unfriendliness. Using extra 50 or even 100% of memory is usually much less problematic than making a lot of random reads.

Comment: Not yet, as I only have the corresponding code in JavaScript (and not in e.g. C++ to check the performance when using OpenGL rather than WebGL). I agree that a bit of additional memory usage is not an issue, but in this case it would be quite a lot — as each vertex in a triangle mesh is typically shared by 5, 6 or 7 edges, it would in general require 500% additional memory... Enough to look for an alternative.

Comment: It's not enough unless it becomes a problem. If your meshes take a total of say 10MB, you can afford 500% without any problems. The random reads can, on the other hand, actually completely trash the performance even with relatively small draws.